# How to link Smartgit to BitBucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, smartgit

I am trying to connect SmartGit/Hg client to my BitBucket account. All of the online search seems to fetch GitHub results.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just noticed that we can connect to BitBucket and select from our repositories from the Clone dialog. Thanks Lazy Badger for the pointer.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can I do it with HTTPS instead of SSH?

Answer (score 3):

Latest SmartGit/HG4 (4.0.1 tested) has BitBucket in the list of supported providers

[image]

Comment: If SmartGit/Hg is already set up, you can add/modify your BitBucket account in the Preferences, section "Hosting Providers".

Answer (score 1):

If you clone from [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) via command-line and add the project to SmartGit, you should be [golden](http://tech.leolink.net/2012/11/how-to-install-and-config-smartgit-git.html).